# Reverse-Proxy login page not works on Apache2

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, login

I'm trying to setup a reverse-proxy on a debian11 with apache2 and it works but when you access the serveur on background by the reverse at the beginning you arrive on a login page in the application but nothing work, we can click on the button like "login" or "forget password" but nothing happens.

This is my configuration :

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName proxy.exemple.fr
   ServerAdmin admin@exemple.fr

   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/cert.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/cert.pkey

   SSLProxyEngine on
   SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
   SSLProxyCheckPeerName Off
   SSLProxyVerify none

   ProxyPass / https://application-we-are-trying-to-access/
   ProxyPassReverse / https://application-we-are-trying-to-access/
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   SecRuleEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

But when you access at the application through the lan with URL without passing by the reverse-proxy, the login page works perfectly

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can try:

Check the network tab in your browser's developer console for errors.
Add "SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1" before the "ProxyPass" directives.
Ensure the application uses relative URLs for resources.
Check server logs for errors or warnings.
Add logging for the reverse proxy using "LogLevel", "CustomLog", and "ErrorLog" directives.

Comment: I check the network tab and that say the server can't charged the .js script but i don't know why. Maybe the rights to access the file on the server I'm trying to attach but I don't think so